# How recursion stops without escape sequence

Tags: c

In code of quicksort algorithm there is and usage of recursion without escape sequence, but the recursion stops and code finishes till end.I have found many code examples of this algorithm, but with escape sequence and this doesnt have one and still works.

I have tried to write everything on paper, but cant find why recursion stops, so function recursively continues forever,

```c
  /* C implementation QuickSort */
  #include<stdio.h> 

  // A utility function to swap two elements 

    void swap(int* a, int* b) 
    { 
      int t = *a; 
      *a = *b; 
      *b = t; 
    } 

  /* This function takes last element as pivot, places 
   the pivot element at its correct position in sorted 
    array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot) 
   to left of pivot and all greater elements to right 
   of pivot */

     int partition (int arr[], int low, int high) 
    { 
      int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot 
      int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) 
    { 
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (arr[j] < pivot) 
        { 
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element 
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]); 
    return (i + 1); 
  } 

  /* The main function that implements QuickSort 

     arr[] --> Array to be sorted, 
     low  --> Starting index, 
     high  --> Ending index */

      void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
     { 
       if (low < high) 
      { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

        // Separately sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
       } 
      } 

  /* Function to print an array */

    void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
    { 
     int i; 
     for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
     printf("n"); 
    }
```

// Driver program to test above functions

```
int main() 
{ 
int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5}; 
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
quickSort(arr, 0, n-1); 
printf("Sorted array: n"); 
printArray(arr, n); 
return 0; 
}
```

In my point of view function would be stucked on 
  quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
continues even when parameter at position pi - 1 reaches 0
but it obviously doesnt.
and arr ends up sorted in 1 5 7 8 9 10

Comment: By "escape sequence" you mean "base case" ?

Comment: Your *base case* is when `if (low < high)` is false.

Comment: probably yes, something which stops recursion(termination)

Comment: @Eugene Sh. omg im so blind, didnt see it for 30 min.Thank you so much now i see and understand sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Your base case is when if (low < high) is false, by Eugene Sh.